# Same behaviour for minzoom for google maps api and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, google-maps-api, zoom, leaflet-draw

I need to implement the same behavior for leaflet and google maps for the case of minzoom. Google maps duplicates all the objects from the main map to the world`s copies, however leaflet doesn't since leaflet range is not limited between -180 180 . So I need either prevent coping on google maps or clone every objects on leaflet.

- There is an option `optimized` for markers in the google api, but other objects types (polygons, polylines) do not support this option.
- And for the leaflet there is a way to set multiple coordinates manually (or may be some plugin exists?).

What is a suitable solution for this issue?